# Commutative algebraic groups endowed with a ring action

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be an arbitrary closed field (of arbitrary characteristic). Assume that we have a short exact sequence of k-algebraic abelian connected groups 
$$
1\rightarrow K\rightarrow G \rightarrow H\rightarrow 1
$$
where $H$ is an abelian variety and $K$ is a (commutative) 
linear algebaic group. Assume moreover (if it helps) that
$$
1\rightarrow Lie(K)\rightarrow Lie(G) \rightarrow Lie(H)\rightarrow 1
$$
is exact. Let $R$ be a ring and assume that we have an injection 
$\rho:R\rightarrow End_k(G)$.

Q: Does $\rho$ necessarily restrict to $K$?

Comment: If I don't miss anything, the question is just whether every element of $End_k(G)$ stabilizes $K$. I guess $K$ is the intersection of all homomorphisms from $G$ to abelian varieties, which suggests a positive answer.

Comment: Indeed [Chevalley structure theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley's_structure_theorem) tells you that the group $K$ is the unique normal linear subgroup of $G$ such that $G/K$ is an abelian variety, so it is preserved by any endomorphism of $G$.

Comment: Nice, so this answers completely my question.

Comment: But doesn't it follow from the simpler observation that if $\theta\in End_k(G)$ and $\pi:G\rightarrow A$ then the map $\pi\circ\theta:K\rightarrow A$ is constant since $K$ is an affine variety and $A$ is projective?

Comment: There can be nontrivial maps from an affine variety into a projective one, think of $\mathbb{A}^n\subset \mathbb{P}^n$. However a linear group is rational (over an algebraically closed field), and there is indeed no nontrivial map from a rational variety into an abelian variety.

Comment: Yes you're right. So I guess that the key point is that a subgroup of an abelian variety is necessarily an abelian variety and a quotient of a linear group is linear. Thus the only linear group which is an abelian variety is the trivial group.

Comment: PS In my previous comment I meant "the intersection of all *kernels of* homomorphisms", of course, sorry for the typo.